# Why my Bitmap after scaling seems empty

Tags: android

I am trying to scale a Bitmap, doubling its size.

But after the scaling the bitmap shows empty, all plain gray...

here is the code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(2, 2);

    // recreate the new Bitmap and set it back
    Bitmap bm2=Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);   
    //bm.recycle();
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I figured it out it's memory issue, if I do it with small images it works fine.

**Still the problem remains with large pictures!!!**

Thanks for any suggestion!!!

Comment: Post your source code or two versions of image both scaled and normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the [Bitmap Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) it is clearly saying that `Bitmap.createBitmap()` returns the same bitmap or part of the source bitmap.So may be here it returns the same bitmap object.But here you are recycling it

```
bm.recycle();
```

thats why you are getting null

Use this method

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

and pass width as 1920 and height as 2560

Comment: thanks kalyan, same result if I don't recycle.. :-((

Comment: is any bitmap is returning or its null??

Comment: it's not null, and while debugging it show correctly double width and double heigh, but it all gray... :-((